# Complex Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model structure as below:

1. User has many Surveys through ResponseSets(user can attend same survey multiple times there by creating ResponseSets for each attempt).
2. ResponseSet has many Responses
3. Response belongs to Questions, Answers and ResponseSets.

I need a rails query to find:

1. How many users have selected a given answer in their last ResponseSet(means last attempt) for that given survey corresponding to answer.
2. How many users have selected a given question in their last ResponseSet(means last attempt) for that given survey corresponding to question.

Comment: `response_set` has_one `user` ?

Comment: Better yet, `response_set` `belongs_to` `user` ?

Comment: I have worked on a very similar problem and look forward to you getting a great answer.  The issue is not so much coming up with a query, it's getting reasonable efficiency.  Getting the last response per user and per question requires an index scan no matter how you slice it.  I think you will have to do what I did: use callbacks to maintain a `LastResponseSetByUser` table so a simple join will get what you need. If you don't get anything better, I will provide a post with details.

Comment: What attribute would you use to determine the 'last' ResponseSet - `created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`?

Comment: @Gene - Please if you could. Really desperate on this from morning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using PostgreSQL, I would recommend using a window function within a subquery to simplify the logic.  The subquery would collect all response_sets for the given query.  The outer query filters to the last ResponseSet per User for that Survey (based on rowNum produced by the window function), as well as ensuring that it contains a response associated with the given answer:

```
select_sql <<-SELECT
  response_sets.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY response_sets.user_id ORDER BY response_sets.id DESC) as rowNum
SELECT

subquery = survey.response_sets.select(select_sql).to_sql

ResponseSet.joins(:responses).from(Arel.sql("(#{subquery}) response_sets")).
            where(responses: {answer_id: answer.id}).
            where("rowNum = 1").count
```

Note that this assumes that a given answer can only be used once per ResponseSet.  If this is not the case, you can refine this further by replacing `.count` with `.count(:distinct => :user_id)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. A given answer can be appear duplicated in many ResponseSets, beacuse a user has provision to attend a Survey multiple times and give same answer all the time. But inside a response_set a user can use an answer only once. Can you please add the other condition too without editing this one.

Comment: If a single ResponseSet can only be associated with an answer once, then this should work for you.  Only the 'latest' ResponseSet for each user is included, and then one record for each matching answer is included in the count.  Updated to demonstrate how COUNT(DISTINCT) is performed.

Comment: Thanks will give this a try and let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will work like a charm, but do watch performance carefully when the ResponseSets table gets large...

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need a subquery or Postgresql `WITH` clause to find the latest responses, which gets quite expensive even with indices if there are many ReponseSets.

On the other hand, if you have a table that contains only the latest responses, then straightforward nested joins will serve.  If I am understanding your schema, correctly, then these are close:

```
User.count(:joins => { :survey => {:latest_response_set => { :response => :answer }}}, 
           :conditions => ['answers.id = ?', answer_id])

User.count(:joins => { :survey => {:latest_response_set => { :response => :question}}}, 
           :conditions => ['questions.id = ? and surveys.id = ?', question_id, survey_id])
```

You can update a latest response table with an `after_save` callback.  This is relatively safe because callbacks are wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give this a try for sure and get back to you. Appreciate the helping mentality :)

Comment: Callbacks are relatively safe - but not entirely.  They work well until concurrent requests come in, which can occur more commonly than you might think.  Depending on how the data is entered, this may not be a problem for you.

Comment: @PinnyM can you explain how they can be unsafe?  With wrapping in an ACID transaction (guaranteed by the Rails spec), either the save (INSERT or UPDATE) and all SQL in the callbacks must complete atomically or a rollback occurs and none complete.  Where would the unsafeness occur?

Comment: After inserting the response_sets there is a potential for a race condition between the 2 transactions as to which request will update the 'latest_response_set_id' cache last.  Whichever updates that field last will persist for the long term, regardless of whether that response_set is actually the 'latest' one (higher id in this implementation).  This is an inherent limitation to maintaining caches via application level callbacks - not specific to ActiveRecord.  There are solutions, but they involve some form of messiness regardless of how they are implemented.

Comment: @PinnyM This does not make sense to me as if it were true, the same could happen with two simple saves occurring concurrently.  During a save the id cache update must be a single transaction with the insert, no?  Thanks.

Comment: @Gene: Absolutely, 2 simple saves that occur concurrently are subject to the same race condition.  The cache UPDATE is bound with the INSERT of that transaction, but both can occur and still result in this problem since no exception was thrown.  ACID won't solve issues with concurrent updates by itself - that's where locking (optimistic/pessimistic) and constraints come in.

Comment: @PinnyM I'm trying to see it. There are going to be two or more concurrent transactions of the form [ update/get next id from id table, insert with this id, callback actions ].  ACID is going to make these run in sequence.  Therefore the ACID transaction ordering _is_ id ordering AFACS. Where is my logic wrong?

Comment: ACID does _not_ guarantee the sequence of concurrent transactions. It simply guarantees that all statements in each transaction either run in their entirety or not at all.  It will also guarantee that a single command (not so easily interpreted) will use an 'immutable snapshot' of affected rows during its execution.  This doesn't hold true across multiple SQL statements within a transaction, and in some cases not even for a single statement containing multiple 'commands'  (e.g. `INSERT INTO (...) SELECT` actually consists of 2 commands).

Comment: @Gene: see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control#Why_is_concurrency_control_needed.3F) for more on this.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  I was assuming transaction isolation level = serializable!